# Input field is being treated as a password field when nothing indicates that it is one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I am working on the front page of a website, in this context on the signup/login form combo. Those forms use the native forms from mobx-react, composed of a `form.js` observer, giving each element it's DOM structure, and a corresponding `template.js` file defining the role of each field. That means I can make nondescript fields in `form.js` and define them in `template.js`.
Sadly, one of my fields is being converted into a password input when nothing should make it one.

Here's a snip from `form.js`

```
export default observer(({ form }) => {
  const isSuccess = state => (!state ? 'is-success' : 'is-danger');

  return (
    <article className='tiles is-ancestor is-inline-flex drc-column'>
      <div className='tile is-vertical is-size-4 has-text-centered has-text-grey'>Inscription</div>
      <form className='tile is-parent is-vertical'>
        // good field
        <div className='tile is-child'>
          <label className='has-text-centered is-block' htmlFor={form.$('surname').id}>
                {form.$('surname').label}
            <input className={`input is-medium has-background-white-ter ${form.$('surname').isEmpty ? '' : isSuccess(form.$('surname').error)}`} id='signup-surname' {...form.$('surname').bind()} />
          </label>
          <p className='has-text-danger'>{form.$('surname').error}</p>
        </div>
        // multiple good fields
        <button className='tile is-child button is-large has-background-success is-fullwidth has-text-white' type='submit' onClick={form.onSubmit}><span className='is-size-6 is-uppercase'>Je m&apos;inscris</span></button>

        <p className={form.error ? 'has-text-danger' : 'has-text-success'}>{form.error}</p>
      </form>
    </article>
  );
});
```

and here's the other side of the coin, on `template.js`

```
  setup() {
    return {
      fields: [{
        name: 'name',
        label: 'Prénom',
        rules: 'required|string'
      }, {
        name: 'surname',
        label: 'Nom',
        rules: 'required|string'
      }, {
        name: 'company',
        label: 'Entreprise',
        rules: 'required|string'
      }, {
        name: 'phone',
        label: 'Numéro de téléphone',
        rules: 'required|numeric'
      }, {
        name: 'email',
        label: 'E-mail',
        rules: 'required|email|string'
      }, {
        name: 'password',
        label: 'Mot de passe',
        rules: 'required|string',
        type: 'password'
      }]
    };
  }
```

Here are [a screenshot of the form itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCcKn.png), and [of the actual interpreted HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIwbd.png).

I want that `surname` field to be a regular text input, not a password input.
I can't redo the tech stack at this point to exclude using the forms from mobx-react, and it used to work just fine. Nothing is overwriting those input fields, those two snips are the only ones in control, I'm not sure where to look next.

Good day!

Comment: I should also add that this isn't a 100% error, rather it seems to occur when you switch from the `login` screen, where there is an `e-mail` and `password` field to the `signup` screen, containing a text field instead of a password field. I'm still looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved.
When you were redirected (manually or otherwise) from the login form to the signup form, the fields were not reset. Since the second field on the login form was a password, it transitioned into the second field of the signup form, keeping the password type.
Resetting said fields with the `componentWillUnmount` mobx hook effectively fixes this issue:

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    const { profileStore } = this.props;
    profileStore.resetFields();
  }
```

And into profileStore itself:

```
  @observable fields = undefined;

  @action
  resetFields() {
    log.warn('resetFields');
    this.fields = undefined;
  }
```

Now forms are effectively recreated from the ground up every time, no more problem.

Answer (score -4):

Just made some slight changes, this should work now dude :)))))

export default observer(({ form }) => {
  const isSuccess = state => (!state ? 'is-success' : 'is-danger');

return (
    
      Inscription
      
        // good field
        
          
                {form.$('surname').label}
            
          
          {form.$('surname').error}

// multiple good fields
        Je m'inscris

```
    <p className={form.error ? 'has-text-danger' : 'has-text-success'}>{form.error}</p>
  </form>
</article>
```

);
});

Comment: Please [edit] your post to format it properly and explain the changes you've made.